If statement based on function allocation in R
I'm working on an algorithm that works with a few different nested functions. On the global layer, depending on the input, I assign different functions to a global function
gradient_fcn

So if the user picks "Binomial", I set
gradient_fcn = binomial_grad

which is a function specified elsewhere. Further down in the nested layers, I reach a point where I want to evaluate a line depending on which type of gradient function is used:
if (gradient_fcn == binomial_grad){a=1} else {a=2}

However, I get the error
Error in gradient_fcn == binomial_grad: 
  comparison (==) is possible only for atomic and list types

I've tried gradient_fcn == "binomial_grad", but with the same error.

Try if (identical(gradient_fcn, binomial_grad))
